# How to create my own scripts in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I am building an `node`application, it has 3 environments names are `development,testing and production`. Each environment has their own hostnames and port numbers. like in the following way

```
{
"development":{
"host":"develop.com",
"port":"2000"
},
"testing":{
"host":"testing.com",
"port":"2001"
},
"production":{
"host":"production.com",
"port":"2002"
}
}
```

While running my `node` application, I used to pass environment name as a command argument. like

```
node server.js development
  (or)                       
node server.js production
```

Instead of running application manually along with environment name, I want to implement with node scripts, so I have tried in the following way.

package.json

```
{
  "developemnt":"node server.js development",
  "production":"node server.js production",
  "testing":"node server.js testing"
}
```

What I thought, Instead of `node server.js development`, I can run `npm development`. This way I have made it, but it's not working. Regarding this, I have read `npm script` documentaion, as per documentation It's not possible,so is there any way to implement this.

Thanks

Comment: I don't know if this is a typo but you package.json says: `developemnt` instead of `development`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For scripts that are not "default scripts" (the ones listed [here](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scripts)), you need to use the `run` parameter with npm:

```
npm run development

npm run testing

npm run production
```

More details [here](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/run-script).